Convergence in probability and a fraction
Suppose $a_n$ is a real valued deterministic sequence and $Z_n$ is real valued stochastic sequence. Suppose further that
\begin{equation*}
a_n\rightarrow 0
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
Z_n\cdot 1_{\{|Z_n|\leq a_n\}}\overset{p}\rightarrow 0.
\end{equation*}
Under what condition can we have
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a_n}{Z_n\cdot 1_{\{|Z_n|\leq a_n\}}}\overset{p}\rightarrow 1?
\end{equation*}

What have you tried?

Have thought about this for a while, but not sure where to even start. When we have deterministic $a_n\rightarrow0$ and $b_n\rightarrow0$, then I suppose $a_n/b_n\rightarrow 1$ iff $a_n=b_n$ no?

How do you define your ratio when the denominator is $0$?

I thought it would be fine if both the denominator and numerator converge to the same quantity
